# onChange event won't trigger on select after options are rendered from a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, jsx

When the user selects an option, it must fire up and change a state variable as below:

```
<select
  onChange={(e) => {
    //change state variable here..
    alert(e.target.value);
  }}
  name="company"
  className={inputFieldStyle}
  id="company"
>
 <option className={optionFieldStyle} value="something">
        {value.name}
 </option>
</select>
```

I don't know why but when I mapped the options from an state array that I got after an API call, the onchange event is not firing up. Setter function and value are valid.

My exact code is:

```
<select
  onChange={(e) => {
    setCompanyId(e.target.value);
    alert(e.target.value);
  }}
  name="company"
  className={inputFieldStyle}
  id="company"
>
  {companyList.map((value) => {
    return (
      <option key={value.id} className={optionFieldStyle} value={value.id}>
        {value.name}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</select>;
```

This is how the element is rendered in browser:

```html
<select name="company" class="bg-transparent border-2 border-slate-700 p-2 outline-none my-1 rounded-md w-full" id="company">
   <option class="bg-slate-600 outline-none checked:bg-slate-600" value="64c5ba1ce0d787aa7ece8208">Nabin Electronics Ltd.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why do you expect a change event to fire when there's only one option? Your code will work when there are multiple options and this is not specific to React.

Comment: @Unmitigated, thanks but you know I'm loading options from a state variable and I tried with multiple values but the issue persist.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] (i.e. the minimum amount of code that still shows the issue when run) then? Please ensure that the issue is actually demonstrated by running the code yourself beforehand. The current code shown does not demonstrate any issue.

Comment: @Unmitigated Yep, this above works find but as soon as the options are fetched and state is updated. I have this awkward error, Idk it can be my foolish mistake but I'm not able to figure it out neither on the web or by myself. Please see the code of my `Login.tsx`: https://pastebin.com/YNxhnUmv

Comment: Can you provide a **runnable** example that minimally demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Unmitigated Thank you so much for asking, I have deployed this for you: https://stock-ms.vercel.app/
You can create a new company with this details:
`companyName, email, username and password` by hitting this endpoint: `https://stock-ms-server-dev.onrender.com/`

Comment: Method: `POST`,
Path: `/signup`

Comment: @Unmitigated thanks for trying to help me, but this actually works after deployment :/